# How to open Firefox in kiosk mode and point to a webpage?

Tags: boot, bash, chromium, web-browsers, kiosk

I'm trying to run Firefox in kiosk mode.

```
nano /home/pi/.config/lxsession/autostart

@firefox-esr (@iceweasel)
```

Here, how to point the browser to a webpage?

Example - for Chromium we use this-  `@chromium-browser --kiosk http://google.com/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

firefox --help seems to give this option:

```
  --kiosk Start the browser in kiosk mode.
```

I have tried with

`firefox --kiosk https://www.ghacks.net/2019/10/07/firefox-71-new-kiosk-mode-for-the-browser/`, alas, this is only from version 71 up, that will take some time to land in ESR/IceWeasel.

So, unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be an easy way to do that, currently.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to run Firefox in kiosk mode on RPi. You’ll need a small hack to emulate hitting the F11 key though.

First install `firefox-esr`:

```
sudo apt install firefox-esr
```

Then you’ll need to install `xdotool`, which is a tool to do fake keyboard input, among others.

```
sudo apt install xdotool
```

Then, in your autostart file you add the following:

```
firefox -kiosk -private-window "http://localhost/" &
sleep 10
xdotool search --sync --onlyvisible --name firefox key F11
```

This will launch Firefox with the desired URL. Then, after ten seconds (you might need a bit more if it takes a longer time to start Firefox) `xdotool` will set focus to Firefox and hit the F11 key. *The `&` behind the URL is essential.*

Sources:

- [one of the other answers to this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/116349/124721)
- [an answer to a similar question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/53300/124721)
- This excellent guide: [Setup a Raspberry Pi to run a Web Browser in Kiosk Mode](https://die-antwort.eu/techblog/2017-12-setup-raspberry-pi-for-kiosk-mode/)

Answer (score 0):

You can install `firefox-esr` on RPi now

```
sudo apt-get install firefox-esr -y
```

and you can run it in kiosk mode - at least from the browser (<kbd>F11</kbd>)

Firefox says `/[install directory]/firefox -kiosk -private-window [target URL]` should do it but I've not been able to make that work right now

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-enterprise-kiosk-mode

Comment: /usr/bin/firefox --kiosk --private-window "http: //10.0.0.110" (you need the quotes adn take the space out after http:) works insofar as it will open Firefox in a Private Browser window and load the webpage. Unfortunately it won't open in kiosk mode.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a bit playing around with all the parameters and got a solution that seems to work fine on my RPI4B with RaspberryOS bookworm:

```
firefox --display=:0 --kiosk-monitor 0 <URL> --kiosk
```